# Why is Mathematica 10 giving me the junk data from Instagram?

Tags: version-10, social-media

[Instagram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Instagram.html):

```
instagram = ServiceConnect["Instagram"]
```

[image]

ServiceExecute[conn,"request",params] sends a request to the connection identified by conn,  in my example it is Instagram. This seemed like it would be cool functionality in v10. But almost all queries that I form return missing, incomplete, or just wrong data.

Note: I have elided the data for privacy, but rest assured the UserID's are correct.

Bugs with this functionality are quite simple indeed to reproduce:

Search for a user:

```
In[3]:= instagram["UserData", "UserID" -> 10206720]

Out[3]= <|"Website" -> "http://barackobama.com", "Username" -> "barackobama", 
 "FullName" -> "Barack Obama", "Media" -> 179, "FollowedBy" -> 3347187, 
 "Follows" -> 11, "ID" -> "10206720"|>

Import recent media from a user:

In[5]:= instagram["FollowerCount", "UserID" -> 10206720]

Out[5]= 50
```

Comment: What is the definition of `instagram`?

Comment: this comment made me laugh so hard.

Comment: please see my above edit

Comment: seems that 50 != 3347187

Comment: Hi M.R., please do not use the bug tag until it has been confirmed as a bug. Also, you have been around for long enough to know how to format code and provide definitions of any custom functions. Unless we know the definition of `instagram`, which does not appear to be a built-in function, we can't help you. It appears to be the name you have given to an `Association`, but this needs to be clearer in the question.

Comment: ok sorry about using the term bug. the example comes straight from the docs, where instagram = ServiceConnect["Instagram"]

Comment: When using examples from the documentation please include a link, or if that is not possible at least reference the page by name.  I did this for you here.

Comment: Do you still have problems with junk using ServiceConnect?

Comment: Yes. Do you have an Instagram account?